# How to add style to nth list item, including list items in nested list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a nested list that looks something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2
    <ul>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li>Item 5
    <ul>
        <li>Item 6
        <ul>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
        </ul></li>
        <li>Item 9</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

If I want to apply a bottom margin to every third `<li>`, meaning Item 3, Item 6, and Item 9, how would I do that?

I looked at using `li:nth-child(3)` and `li:nth-of-type(3)` and neither worked. Those selectors don't count the way I need.

Comment: `nth` of anything relates to parents and so your selector will not work as the items do not share a parent.

Comment: First you need to fix your HTML.

Comment: Why don't you want to do this with jquery/javascript?

Comment: Firstly, fix your list nesting: https://jsfiddle.net/2q08gt2m/

Comment: Michael_B - fair enough. This still doesn't get me to the full answer, though. Editing original post.

Comment: There is no *single* `nth` CSS selector that will do what you want.

Comment: Is there anything special about every third li?

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution using [CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) but no luck.

Comment: @j08691 - Not exactly. 3 `<li>`s take up x amount of space so I'm trying to break the overall list up evenly by number of elements for visual reasons.

Comment: Any adjustment to each 3rd item will break this open to a simple CSS solution. Add a class or another attribute, wrap the content in each 3rd item in a `div` or a `span`, etc. Then they're easy to target.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to fix the wrong problem. If this is spacing issue perhaps you could ask a NEW question with what you have and what you'd like to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, since your `<li>` tags don't share a parent, child relationships aren't going to accomplish what you're after.

It looks like your best bet here is modifying the HTML one way or another to attach some classes or style properties directly.

This might be simply changing the HTML itself, or using a little JS to loop through all of those `<li>` tags and add a class or change style properties on the fly.

Comment: Yeah, it's looking like JS might be the best option. I was hoping there was a simple CSS selector that could count every `li` contained inside a particular block, regardless of parent/child relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this cannot be cleanly achieved with nested lists. If you only had one list, this effect could be achieved with the CSS:

```
li:nth-child(3n+0){
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that CSS will not continue to count list items in a nested list, and will count each list as starting at 1. The easiest way I've found to achieve what you want would be to create a new class and then apply that class to each element you want underlined as such:

```
.margin{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

and then apply `class = "margin"` or whatever you've named it to each element you want underlined, your new code being:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2
    <ul>
        <li class = "margin">Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li>Item 5
    <ul>
        <li class = "margin">Item 6
        <ul>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
        </ul></li>
        <li class = "margin">Item 9</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

I hope this was helpful

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing. The list was being created dynamically, though, so I had to use a little JS to count the elements and add the `margin` class, otherwise I would have accepted your answer.